# Init() and __constructor in YII

Tags: php, yii2

i'm new in YII and I want to set in my constructor something like

```
public function __construct(Car $car)
{
    $this->car= $car;
}
```

and use my model to peform the query anything like

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->car->select('id','color')->all();

    $this->render('index', array( 'car' => $car));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Yii than there is no need to inject $car in controller constructor.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $cars = Car::find()->all();
    return $this->render('index', [
        'cars' => $cars
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This method is specific to Yii2 not Yii - just so OP knows

Comment: It looks like Lucas using Yii2 as he uses $this->car->select()->all(); Yii doesn't have all() function, Yii has findAll();

Comment: Thanks for updating tag to Yii2 :)

Comment: But if i want to add another class like driver of the car i inject in constructor? how I do it ?

Comment: You can do the same Driver::find()->all(); You can use any model in any controller. But its better to keep it secret. You can get benefit of relations as well. Suppose you have Driver for Cars than create relation and you can access driver data from Car object.